# Does my code execute when my app is updated?

Tags: android

I want to check my android app first running. So my code is follwing.

This code is successfully executed when my app is first installed.

But, i'm not sure it is executed when my app is updated through App Store.

Is it executed when my android app is updated through App Store?

```
public boolean CheckAppFirstExecute(){
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("isFirst" , Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isFirst = pref.getBoolean("isFirst", false);
    if(!isFirst) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isFirst", true);
        editor.commit();

        ....


    }else{
        Log.d("this is not first", "not first");
    }

    return !isFirst;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I guess you want to ask the value of isFirst but not "if the code is executed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared preferences are not reset during an update. So your "first use" code will not run again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the values in `SharedPreference` will not be dropped after an update through the Playstore or any manual apk install with `install -r xx.apk`